# Phrasing GitHub JSON API in PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm currently writing a PHP script to find a user's GitHub email address via the GitHub API (`https://api.github.com/users/{username}/events`).

I've thought of a way to do this, but I'm having a hard time implementing it into PHP. My thought process is to pull the JSON, search for the 'email' string (using a loop and some RegEx) and then returning the result.

This is my PHP so far (I'm still new to the language):
https://hastebin.com/wuzezotuqi.xml

Comment: Do you need to store the email address into the server side or its only purpose is to shown into the client side ?

Comment: @RatulSharker It just needs to be shown onto the client side

Comment: @RatulSharker Sorry for the late response, could you also show me the server side (PHP) proposed solution? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: i've updated the answer, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **javascript** in the client side browser to fetch the email.

```
//parse the response for the email.
function reqListener () {
  var para = document.getElementById('textpad');
    var emailIndex = this.responseText.indexOf("email");

    var nextColonIndex = this.responseText.indexOf(":", emailIndex);
    var nextCommanIndex = this.responseText.indexOf(",", emailIndex);

    var emailAddr = this.responseText.substr(nextColonIndex + 1, nextCommanIndex-nextColonIndex - 1);
}


//
// making the api request
//
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
oReq.open("GET", "https://api.github.com/users/ratulSharker/events");
oReq.send();
```

Check it on action in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sharker08/4hy5aj94/2/)

Incase you intend to do it in server side using **PHP**

```
<?php

$config['useragent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $config['useragent']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.github.com/users/ratulSharker/events');
        $content = curl_exec($ch);



$emailIndex = strpos($content, "email", 0);     // find from the start


$nextColonIndex = strpos($content, ":", $emailIndex);
$nextCommanIndex = strpos($content, "," , $emailIndex);
$nextQuoteIndex = strpos($content, "\"", $nextColonIndex);
$nextNextQuoteIndex = strpos($content, "\"", $nextQuoteIndex+1);



    $emailAddr =  substr($content, $nextQuoteIndex, $nextNextQuoteIndex-$nextQuoteIndex+1);

echo $emailAddr;
```

Check the code in action in [PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/fhu8-2svq)